# Does GCC infer return statements for functions?

Tags: c, gcc

I just encountered a very strange interaction with GCC and C that I would not have caught without -Wall:

```
// infer.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Test {
    int dummy;
} Test;

Test* test_make() {
    Test *ret = malloc(sizeof(Test));
    ret->dummy = 1;
    // return nothing
}

int main() {
    Test* t = test_make();
    printf("%i\n", t->dummy);
}
```

As you can see, test_make does NOT return anything despite the return type promising a pointer to my struct.

Compiling with gcc (without warnings) results in no complaints:

```
gcc -o infer infer.c
```

And running the program produces the expected behavior:

```
./infer
1
```

I am confused at how my program ran successfully. Does GCC infer the return type of functions if there is no explicit return statement?

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Compiling with -Wall clearly catches that something is up, but how does GCC let this program compile (let alone run) successfully at all?

Comment: This is undefined behavior, anything can happen. By accident it happens to be returning what you want.

Comment: GCC doesn't have to infer the type, since that' already in the declaration. I assume you're asking if it's inferring the _value_?

Comment: *but how does GCC let this program compile* - C is very pemissive and will let you shoot your own feet if you would like to. It might warn you though.

Comment: Note that `main` is a special case and if you omit a `return` statement, it automatically returns 0.  That's why you're getting a warning for `test_make` but not for `main`.